# Cannot insert java.time.LocalDateTime with zero seconds

Tags: mysql, kotlin, ktorm

Kotlin: 1.6.20

Ktorm: 3.4.1

MySQL Connector/J: 8.0.28

C3P0 Connection Pool: 0.9.5.5

I seem to be having a problem with "datetimes" (LocalDateTime) that have zero seconds. I know this would look like an issue with the JDBC driver but I tested the driver and it does not even accept LocalDateTime (only java.util.Date). This issue does not come up if the LDT does have seconds.

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Am I missing some configuration?
- Have I got the types wrong?
- Does anyone know of a workaround?

A minimum test that I am using to isolate the issue

```
const val tableName = "test"
const val fieldName = "ldt"

interface TestRecord : Entity<TestRecord> {

    companion object : Entity.Factory<TestRecord>()

    val ldt: LocalDateTime
}

object TestTable : Table<TestRecord>(tableName) {

    val ldt = datetime(fieldName).bindTo { it.ldt }
}

class BlahTest {

    @Test
    fun a() {

        val dataSource = DbConfig.from("test.properties").provideDataSource()
        dataSource.connection.use {
            it.prepareStatement("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $tableName").execute()
            it.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tableName ($fieldName TIMESTAMP)").execute()
        }
        val db = Database.connect(dataSource = dataSource, dialect = MySqlDialect())
        val tb = TestTable
        val ldt = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
            //.plusSeconds(1) // with anything but 0 it will work
        db.insertOrUpdate(TestTable) {
            set(tb.ldt, ldt)
        }
    }
}
```

Produces an error

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '1970-01-01 00:00:00' for column 'ldt' at row 1
```

Ktorm issue: https://github.com/kotlin-orm/ktorm/issues/391

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is formatting the timestamp value 0 as '1970-01-01 00:00:00', but MySQL is not.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html says:

> MySQL converts `TIMESTAMP` values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as `DATETIME`.)

For example, I'm in PDT, so when I try to insert a timestamp value 0, it adjusts it by 8 hours to '1969-12-31 16:00:00', which is not a legal value in the range for the `TIMESTAMP` type.

```
mysql> create table tablename (ldt timestamp);

mysql> insert into tablename values (from_unixtime(0));
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '1969-12-31 16:00:00' for column 'ldt' at row 1
```

So you could make sure to account for timezone when you generate your "zero" value to insert into a `TIMESTAMP`.

Or you could use `DATETIME`.

```
mysql> alter table tablename modify ldt datetime;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into tablename values (from_unixtime(0));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

I recommend using `DATETIME` anyway, because it supports a greater range of dates than `TIMESTAMP`. This will become important [if you need to store dates past 2038-01-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: The solution I am looking for does not involve writing bare mysql statements. I am working inside Ktorm with kotlin and MySQL datasource

Comment: How do you think Ktorm inserts a timestamp?

Comment: Genius! But would that mean that this is beyond ktorm and all my other tables which are already timestamp are screwed?

Comment: Yes, if you insist on inserting zero-valued timestamps. I'd recommend using ALTER TABLE and change TIMESTAMP columns to DATETIME.